# Continuity of $f^{(n-1)}$ in Taylor's Theorem with Mean-value remainder

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, continuity, taylor-expansion

I refer to Rudin's proof of Taylor's Theorem with the Mean-value form of the remainder.

[image: Taylor's theorem]

I'm not sure if I'm understanding the proof correctly. Why must $f^{(n-1)}$ be continuous on $[a,b]$? I believe continuity at the endpoints is only used in the application of the mean value theorem for $g(\beta)$ and $g(\alpha), g'(\alpha), \cdots, g^{(n-1)}(\alpha)$. Also, I don't get the point of $a$ and $b$. Thus, is it ok to restate Taylor's theorem as follows:

Suppose $f : D \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous on $[\alpha, \beta] \subseteq D$, $n$ is a positive integer, $f^{(n-1)}$ is continuous on $[\alpha, \beta)$, $f^{(n)}(t)$ exists for every $t \in (\alpha, \beta)$. Then there exists a point $x \in (\alpha, \beta)$ such that

$$f(\beta) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{f^{(k)}(\alpha)}{k!}(\beta-\alpha)^k + \frac{f^{(n)}(x)}{n!}(\beta-\alpha)^k.$$

I checked the statement of the theorem on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulae_for_the_remainder) and it also has the condition of continuity of $f^{(n-1)}$ on the closed interval between $\alpha$ and $\beta$. So I thought I might be missing something. Thanks!

Comment: So you can prove the Mean Value Theorem without assuming that $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$. Can you show us a complete proof?

Comment: @Siminore Yes, the Mean Value Theorem requires $f$ to be continuous on $[a,b]$. However in Rudin's proof, he only uses the mean value theorem for $g$ on $[\alpha, \beta]$, $g'$ on $[\alpha, x_1]$, $g''$ on $[\alpha, x_2]$, etc. So I thought $f^{(n-1)}$ need only be continuous on $[\alpha, \beta)$ and not $[\alpha, \beta]$, if we also have $f$ continuous on $[\alpha, \beta]$. Is there something wrong with this reasoning?

Comment: In the case $n = 1$, you need the continuity of $f^{(n-1)}$ on $[\alpha,\beta]$ (or $[\beta,\alpha]$ if $\beta < \alpha$). For $n > 1$, you can work without the continuity of $f^{(n-1)}$ at $\beta$. But it's simpler to state the theorem without that distinction. And you practically never need the slightly more general case, so why would you?

Comment: @Wakaka But the MVT for $g$ is the MVT. How can you start the proof if the assumptions of the MVT are violated?

Comment: @DanielFischer I think that you always start the proof with $n=1$ (applied to $g$). Then you focus on a smaller interval, but how do you choose $x-1$ if the MVT is not applicable to $g$ on the whole $[\alpha,\beta]$?

Comment: @Siminore So the MVT requires $f$ to be continuous on $[\alpha, \beta]$ in all cases. But for $n > 1$, I think since we only need to apply MVT on a smaller interval, so we only require $f^{(n-1)}$ to be continuous on $[\alpha, \beta)$ (but $f$ must still be continuous on $[\alpha, \beta]$).

Comment: @DanielFischer I see, I just want to make sure I'm understanding the proof correctly since all the sources I see require that condition. Thanks!

Comment: @Siminore That's my point, if $n = 1$, you need the continuity of $f^{(n-1)}$ on the whole closed interval (well, $[\alpha,\beta]$). But if $n > 1$, it would suffice to require the continuity of $f', f'',\dotsc, f^{(n-1)}$ on the half-open interval. (But what's the point of complicating the statement of the theorem in that way?)

Comment: @DanielFischer I'm probably tired, but how can you do the first step?

Comment: @Siminore For the first step, we need the continuity of $f$ on $[\alpha,\beta]$ (or $[\beta,\alpha]$), and the existence of $f'$ on $(\alpha,\beta)$ (or ...). We have that in the premises, so all is fine. For the second step, we need the continuity of $f'$ on $[\alpha, x_1]$ (or ...) and the existence of $f''$ on $(\alpha, x_1)$ (...), and so on. We can (**very** slightly) relax the continuity requirements on the derivatives starting from $f'$, but not the continuity requirement on $f$.